# Probability of interest rate hike using 30 and 60 day rates

Tags: interest-rates

How can I calculate the probability of a rate hike of 25 bps if 30 day rate is 3% and 60 day rate is 3.1%? I thought I need the implied federal funds rate but it is not given.

Answer (score 1):

Market participants usually look at the Eurodollar, Euribor, Short Sterling strips etc. These are discrete forecasts of a rate at a discrete point in time. So if Mar is 3.0% and Jun is 3.1%, then there is a 40% chance of a 25bp hike priced in Q2 etc.

For your example, it's 80%. There are two scenarios = unchanged, or a hike. If unchanged, then I compound two months of current 3.0% annual rates. 1 becomes 1.00494. If the hike, then compound one month at 3.0% and one at 3.25%. 1 becomes 1.00514. Compound two months at the 3.1% 60 day rate, 1 becomes 1.00510. This is at the 80% percentile of the range between the two scenarios.

[image]